# ¿Cómo cierro una aplicación que haya ejecutado? Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Estoy intentando hacer una especie de **App** lanzadora de **apps**. El caso es que quiero que cuando dentro de la **app** lanzada (**app** de terceros, por ejemplo Spotify), vuelva a mi aplicación principal (una especie de launcher **app**) y que la aplicación de terceros se cierre. ¿Cómo podría forzar a que se cerrara esta **app** de terceros al entrar/volver a la mía?

Este código uso para lanzar las apps:

```
 protected void appOpener(String nPackage) {
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(nPackage);
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        startActivity(launchIntent); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Desde tu aplicación no puedes cerrar otra aplicación, me refiero a cerrar el `MainActivity`**, esto cambio desde Android Froyo OS 2.2 por cuestiones de seguridad para evitar interferir en otras aplicaciones.

Lo que se puede realizar es termina algún proceso mediante [killBackgroundProcesses()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses(java.lang.String)), esto aplica para un proceso de otra aplicación.